# How to import npm packages in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

Im trying to import a package called [cssdom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssdom) in angular:

like this:

```
import * as CssDom from "cssdom";
```

But I'm getting the following error:

[image]

when I try to create a new instance of CssDom like this:

```
const css = '.container { background-color: white; }';
const cssdom = new CssDom(css)
```

I tried this way also:

```
import {CssDom} from 'cssdom'
```

Or is there a way to import these third party packages in to angular?

In vue-js this is very easy. As you can import simply. But with typescript/angular this seems hard.!

Answer (score 1):

First install cssdom (if not done yet):

```
$ npm i cssdom
```

Solution 1 :

Add the script to `angular.json`

```
  "scripts": [
     ...
    "../node_modules/cssdom/cssdom.js"
     ...
],
```

Next use cssdom like this:

```
declare const CssDom:any;

...

const css = '.container { background-color: white; }';
const cssdom = new CssDom(css)
```

Solution 2 :

```
declare var CssDom:any;

import "cssdom";
```

Comment: Do I need to import the css dom into the component?

Comment: Im getting this error: ```scripts.js:2706 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not define```. This is from the scripts of the above package!!

Comment: Along  with that I'm getting this error also : ```TypeError: Scanner is not a constructor
    at new CssDom```

Comment: You can try me second solution

Comment: new error  ```Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: process is not defined
ReferenceError: process is not defined``` along with ```Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined```